# Python Import running in shell but not in file

Tags: python, system, package

I am using Influxdb python client to write data to Influxdb.

But, I am failing to import the influxdb module in my file.
It successfully gets imported in the shell, but does not work in the file.

Here is the

```
print '\n'.join( sys.path )
```

from my shell

```
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
```

and here is the same from my file,

```
/home/azureuser/pranav/book/vogo-backend-v2/book
/home/azureuser/.virtualenvs/book/lib/python2.7
/home/azureuser/.virtualenvs/book/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/home/azureuser/.virtualenvs/book/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/azureuser/.virtualenvs/book/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/home/azureuser/.virtualenvs/book/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/azureuser/.virtualenvs/book/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/home/azureuser/.virtualenvs/book/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/home/azureuser/pranav/book/vogo-backend-v2/book
```

Here is the

```
sys.executable #from file
/home/azureuser/.virtualenvs/book/bin/python

sys.executable #from the shell
/usr/bin/python
```

If I install it without using sudo pip , then it raises an exception,

```
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
  status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
  requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
  requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 672, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 902, in move_wheel_files
  pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 206, in move_wheel_files
  clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 193, in clobber
  os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
  OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distpackages/influxdb-4.0.0.dist-info'

 Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpokCmFo
```

Please explain why the problem is coming ? and also the solution.

Comment: Are you accessing shell outside virtualenv?

Comment: Well, most likely the module you are trying to import is in one of the paths that you use when using the shell but not when you are running the file directly

Comment: what is the solutin @UnholySheep

Comment: @AbijithMg accessing shell, the same place where my file is

Comment: Find out where the module is and then either copy it to a path (from the second output) or adjust the path when you run the second version

Answer (score 1):

1. First create the virtual environment properly:

   ```
   virtualenv my_env
   ```
2. Activate the virtualenv:

   ```
   source my_env/bin/activate
   ```
3. Inside your virtualenv install the client again using --no-cache-dir flag:

   ```
   pip install influxdb --no-cache-dir
   ```
4. Try accessing the same in your .py files.

This will definitely fix your issue!

Comment: Did u install it via sudo pip install? or just pip install? If sudo it will install in global config, which in turn will not affect your virtualenv!

Comment: using sudo, is that creating the problem?

Comment: Yes! As i said the package will be installed globally and your file will not be access the same as you are in virtual environment. Do as i have mentioned in the answer, it will fix your issue.

Comment: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: it throws this exception then

Comment: Can you update the complete stack trace in your question?

Comment: thank you for your help and being calm. Actually, I wasn't workingin my venv, i then did `workon myvenv` and it worked.

Comment: Do accept the answer. It will help others, who are stuck on the same issue.